# Can't Enable Application Framework even with form as startup object

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a *Windows forms project*, with application framework disabled. I want to enable it to allow for visual styles.

`Application.EnableVisualStyles()` doesn't cover things like trackbars.  I've tested this with separate projects - enabling **application framework** seems to be what I want.

However, in my project, I can't enable the application framework - the option is greyed out.  My Startup Object is definitely a form, but I still can't enable it.

Can you help me figure out what I have to do to enable the application framework for this project?

Comment: `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` does exactly the same thing as "Enable XP visual styles" checkbox.  the App framework code is simply `Me.EnableVisualStyles = true`  where/when you call it is of some import.  Not sure why you can't enable the framework...what are some of the other properties there?

Comment: The "Application Type"  must be "Windows Forms" to for the "Enable Application Framework"  to be enabled.  You may have accidentally changed that.  Try changing to ClassLib, Save then change back.

Comment: Hm - moving `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` from my form load event to the form constructor has had the desired effect of applying visual styles to all controls rather than just some.  Thank you!  I had no idea that would have an impact.  Still a mystery why I can't use the checkbox, no other settings are anything unusual.  If you submit this as an answer I'll tick it.

Comment: If your startup object is not a Form, it should be `Sub Main`.  Put it there before you reference any UI object.

Comment: `Final_gui` would have to be a form for the framework option to be enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not starting from a MainForm, typically you would use a `Sub Main` in a Module:

```
Module Program

    Public Sub Main
        ' normal winforms startup
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.Run(New MainForm)
    End Sub

End Module
```

You must enable visual styles before any UI elements are referenced which is why it wont work from the Form_Load event - it is too late.

Comment: I was starting from a form, hence my confusion when I couldn't enable the application framework, which has starting from a form as a requirement.  The `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` also works correctly when added to the starting form's constructor.

Comment: There might be something "creative" about the form that prevents it.  Using the ctor should work well enough

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for and deleting the binary file "Application.YourApp" under the "My Project" folder of your VB.NET project.

Comment: I've seen this solution before, but my project contains no such file.  Just the manifest, settings and resources under My Project.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can show what your settings Application Settings screen looks like?

Comment: [Here's an imgur.](http://i.imgur.com/RTFA8DN.png)  I've tried more recent frameworks but that hasn't helped.  (Project intended for use on unnetworked machine hence 3.5).  I haven't touched anything else.

Comment: In solution explorer do you have folders or files listed under your "My Project" folder?

Comment: Only those mentioned - app.manifest, resources.resx, Settings.settings.  The latter two have corresponding .designer.vb files.

Answer (score 0):

6 years later, I had the same problem. I had to open the app.manifest file and uncomment a dependency node at the bottom which was preceded by the following comment:

> *Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later)*

If you need to create it the whole section is:

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```